# DAX GENERATE & ALLNOBLANKROW functions lead to circular dependency

Tags: dax

I'm trying to use a DAX function to generate a table in Power BI. I have a fact table with Opened & Closed date columns and there is a requirement to report at the end of each day/month/year how many items were backlogged.

I've got the table to generate successfully with the code below - essentially joining the date and fact tables, however I can't then link it back to my dimensions due to a circular dependency error.

Researching it online suggests that I need to remove the blank row from fact_task_transaction with the ALLNOBLANKROW function. Unfortunately this has no effect.

Can anyone help?

```
Backlog Per Day = 

var res = SELECTCOLUMNS (
    GENERATE (
        fact_task_transaction,
        
        FILTER (                
            ALLNOBLANKROW ( 'Date' ),
            AND(
                'Date'[Date] >= fact_task_transaction[Opened At Date],
                'Date'[Date] <= fact_task_transaction[Closed At Date]
            )
        )
    ),
    "Date", 'Date'[Date],
    "Task ID", fact_task_transaction[Task Id],
    "Assignee ID", fact_task_transaction[Assignee Id]
)

return res
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code - it only uses `fact_task_transaction`, so the joins with dimensions shuld be working fine

```
Backlog Per Day =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    GENERATE (
        'fact_task_transaction',
        GENERATESERIES (
            CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'fact_task_transaction'[Opened At Date] ) ),
            CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'fact_task_transaction'[Closed At Date] ) ),
            1
        )
    ),
    "Date", [Value],
    "Task ID", fact_task_transaction[Task Id],
    "Assignee ID", fact_task_transaction[Assignee Id]
)
```